# Построить график для функции 2 переменных

Tags: python, python-3.x, графика, graph

Всем привет! Возникла задача построить распределение интенсивности излучения лазера на плоскости. Соответственно есть координаты на этой плоскости и значение интенсивности в этих точках. Хочется на графике видеть в каких точках плоскости интенсивность большая, в каких маленькая и т.д. в общем просто видеть распределение этой интенсивности. Функция зависимости интенсивности от координат плоскости имеется, нужно визуализировать. Подскажите пожалуйста как это можно сделать в Python

Comment: почитайте про matplotlib, там можно и а ля температурную карту сделать, и трехмерную поверхность отрисовать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Из той же серии графиков от matplotlib:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

x = np.arange(-5, 5, 0.25)
y = np.arange(-5, 5, 0.25)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
r = np.sqrt(X**2 + Y**2)
Z = np.sin(r)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,10))
ax.pcolormesh(X, Y, Z, cmap='RdBu', vmin=-5, vmax=1)
plt.show()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо вам большое

Answer (score 3):

пример из [документации](https://matplotlib.org/stable/plot_types/arrays/contourf.html#sphx-glr-plot-types-arrays-contourf-py)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.style.use('_mpl-gallery-nogrid')

# make data
X, Y = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(-3, 3, 256), np.linspace(-3, 3, 256))
Z = (1 - X/2 + X**5 + Y**3) * np.exp(-X**2 - Y**2)
levels = np.linspace(Z.min(), Z.max(), 7)

# plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.contourf(X, Y, Z, levels=levels)

plt.show()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо, большое! То что нужно

Comment: @Радмир если ответ участника вам помог, вы можете отметить его как принятый и "плюсануть"

Answer (score 2):

Хочу еще добавить, что можно строить и в 3d, для удобства просмотра. Расписал все подробно

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Задаем значения x, y, z
# Я визуализирую функцию eggholder
X, Y = np.meshgrid([i for i in range(-512, 512)], [i for i in range(-512, 512)])
Z = -(X+47)*np.sin(np.sqrt(abs(X/2 + (Y+47)))) - X*np.sin(np.sqrt(abs(X - (Y+47))))

# Задаем пространство
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d')
# Название нашего объекта --необязательно
ax.set_title('Eggholder')
# Кладем фигуру в пространство с наложенным скином
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, cmap='inferno')
# Смотрим, что вышло
plt.show()
```

Выходит вот такое вот
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Классный способ, спасибо